# Äquivalentes Wort zu "schreibintensiv" für Lesen?

Tags: single-word-request, adjective

Gibt es ein Adjektiv mit der Bedeutung von *zeitintensiv* mit der Beschränkung aufs Lesen?

Zur Verdeutlichung:

- zeitaufwändig, viel zu schreiben ==> schreibintensiv
- zeitaufwändig, viel zu lesen     ==> ???

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, aber ist *leseintensiv* ein passendes Wort? Ich meine, ist das korrektes Deutsch? Hab gerade im internet keine Erklärung davon gefunden, aber es scheint mir so.

Comment: Eigentlich klingt »leseintensiv« gar nicht so schlecht.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Schreibintensiv* ist kein allzu gängiges Wort und wurde soweit noch von keinem Wörterbuch aufgenommen, und da man im Deutschen durch die Komposition ganz viele "korrekte" Begriffe Formen kann (solange sie semantisch Sinn machen), ist *leseintensiv* genau so gutes Deutsch wie *schreibintensiv*.

Da du *schreibintensiv* akzeptiert hast, kannst du also zu *leseintensiv* greifen.

Mir persönlich gefallen übrigens beide nicht und ich würde *zeitintensives/zeitaufwändiges Lesen* verwenden. Oder im Fließtext auch ganz anders, aber dafür bräuchte es mehr Kontext.